# Access body as JSON in ActionBuilder

Tags: json, action, playframework-2.3

I'm using Playframework 2.3.X. I'm trying to construct an action function that validates fields in a JSON request.body. The use case is to build "blocks" of validation that I can then chain together.

However, I can't seem to access the request.body as a JSON inside the action builder. The following doesn't compile. The compiler can't resolve "asJson":

```
def ValidateJsonBodyAction = new ActionBuilder[Request] {

   def invokeBlock[A](request: Request[A], block: (Request[A]) => Future[Result]): Future[Result] = {

       val body= request.body.asJson
   }
}
```

UPDATE: It could also be that I'm approaching this the wrong way. I'm new to play, so alternative approaches are also welcome.

UPDATE: Yes, it appears that a may be doing things the wrong way. I'm not the only one with this issue. See https://github.com/playframework/playframework/issues/3387

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you might have to pattern match on the body type (which I admit is not a beautiful solution):

```
import scala.concurrent.Future.{successful => immediate}

def JsonValidator(validator: Reads[JsValue]) = new ActionBuilder[Request] {

  def jsonBody[A](body: A): Option[JsValue] = body match {
    case js: JsValue => Some(js)
    case any: AnyContent => any.asJson
    case _ => None
  }

  override def invokeBlock[A](request: Request[A], block: (Request[A]) => Future[Result]): Future[Result] = {
    jsonBody(request.body) match  {
      case Some(js) => js.validate(validator) match {
        case JsSuccess(_, _) => block(request)
        case JsError(e) =>  immediate(BadRequest(s"Bad Json: $e"))
      }
      case None =>  immediate(UnsupportedMediaType("Bad content type: expected Json"))
    }
  }
}
```

This is basically what happens behind the scenes when you, for example, [bind a form](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/2.3.x/framework/src/play/src/main/scala/play/api/data/Form.scala#L76) on a request with an arbitrary and unknown body.

**On the other hand** you might find it better to just write a specific `BodyParser` to validate your data, e.g:

```
def jsonFormatParser(validator: Reads[JsValue]): BodyParser[JsValue] = parse.json.validate { js =>
  js.validate(validator) match {
    case JsSuccess(_, _) => Right(js)
    case JsError(e) => Left(BadRequest(s"Json didn't have the right format: $e"))  
  }
}

// A validator which checks the JSON contains a "hello" path which 
// then contains a "world" path
val helloWorldValidator: Reads[JsValue] = Reads.required(__ \ "hello" \ "world")

def helloWorldAction = Action(jsonFormatParser(helloWorldValidator)) { implicit request =>
   Ok("Got the right type of JSON")
}
```

It depends on your use-case. Since JSON validators (`Reads[JsValue]`) are nicely composable via `andThen` that might be your best bet.

Comment: Will try this and report back

Comment: I'm a little torn now. This has the advantage of using the same ActionBuilder template for everything...which is good for maintenance. The code is definitely longer though. Will try the "official" hack and see how that goes.

Comment: The "official" hack can't be used with "andThen" ... at least I don't see a way how (being a noob to scala and play). This looks like the answer for the time being :-)

Comment: Did notice that "expected Json" never gets called. I take it I would have to use a custom parser in order for that to work.

Comment: @UAvalos it should only get called if the request isn't what you expect. Your mileage may vary; body parsers compose nicely as well.